# Would GCC optimize self-refuting conditions within loops?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

If, for example, I have code as below:

```
int b = 0;

// more stuff here

for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
    if ( !b ) {
        b = 1;
    } else {
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

If the first condition is true on the first iteration, it will necessarily never be true on the following iterations (and if it's false on the first iteration, it will also be false on following iterations, as long as `b` isn't modified in the "other stuff" section). So for all iterations of the loop, apart from the first, only the else block will ever run.

Would GCC (or similar compilers) optimise this, by, for example, extracting the code for the first iteration and running it before the loop and then starting the loop from 1 and without the conditional? Or is that something I'd have to do myself if I wanted to be a performance junkie?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the generated code and see?

Comment: This question might be improved by asking for the names of the optimization passes that could do what OP wants.

Comment: Constant propagation will probably take care of this. Compilers might or might not unroll the loop.

Comment: @Barmar - not everyone knows about [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org) and not everyone is confident enough with assembly to know what's really going on.

Comment: @AlexReinking I didn't know about Godbolt. That's a great tool, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends heavily on what is in the commented sections. As written, if you were to put this in a function and simply return `b` like so:

```
int example() {
    int b = 0;
    // more stuff here
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
        if ( !b ) {
            b = 1;
        } else {
            // do some other stuff
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Assuming you've specified `-O2` or higher, then [gcc 4.4.7 and later compile this to](https://godbolt.org/g/rkMrFL):

```
example():
  mov eax, 1
  ret
```

So it completely evaluates the loop. On the other hand, if you have something that depends on `b` and `i` like so:

```
extern int doSomeOtherStuff(int b, int i);

int example() {
    int b = 0;
    // more stuff here (that doesn't interfere with b)
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
        if ( !b ) {
            b = 1;
        } else {
            doSomeOtherStuff(b, i);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Then this is compiled ([by 4.4.7](https://godbolt.org/g/T4hL3S)) to:

```
example():
  push rbx
  xor ebx, ebx
  jmp .L2
.L3:
  mov esi, ebx
  mov edi, 1
  call doSomeOtherStuff(int, int)
.L2:
  add ebx, 1
  cmp ebx, 100
  jne .L3
  mov eax, 1
  pop rbx
  ret
```

Here, we can see that the `mov edi, 1` instruction corresponds to the `b` argument, which is always `1` when `doSomeOtherStuff` is called. By GCC 8.1, it's smart enough to unroll the loop to the first call to `doSomeOtherStuff`, while 4.4.7 emits the whole loop.